# What causes this error when using pip to install library

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install BeautifulSoup, I receive

"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\Lib\site-packages\soupsieve'"

How do I resolve this?

TIA

Comment: Is that all the output? Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix:

```
pip install --user <package_name>
```

Example:

```
pip install --user BeautifulSoup
```

If that still doesn't work, read up on how to upgrade pip using python.

Answer (score 0):

You should first set-up the (Env) means the Virtual Environment for run the this code, for example Ur

> c:\program files (x86)\

this will be look like this (below cmd)

> (Env) c:\the directory of ur project\

and just run the cmd >>

> pip install BeautifulSoup

Or

> pip3 install BeautifulSoup

If you don,t know to how set up virtual env in Windows please see this link  https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/